# kerberos authentication with ODP.NET unmanaged driver C#.NET

Tags: .net, kerberos, odp.net, odp.net-unmanaged

Hi I want to use kerberos authentication with ODP.NET unmanaged driver.
I can connect using "SQLPLUS /@UAT_APP"

I have developed a simple C# console application targeting to .NET framework 4.6.1
below is the code:

```
 DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("oracle.dataaccess.client");
 var con = factory.CreateConnection();
 con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=UAT_APP;";
 con.Open();
```

App.config

```
oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>
        <add name="FetchSize" value="131072"/>
        <add name="StatementCacheSize" value="10"/>
        <add name="TraceFileName" value="C:\Temp\odp.trc"/>
        <add name="TraceLevel" value="127"/>
        <add name="TraceOption" value="0"/>
        <add name="SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES" value="Kerberos5"/>
        <add name="SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF" value="C:\Apps\oracle\network\admin\krb5.conf"/>
        <add name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\Apps\oracle\network"/>
    </settings>
</oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

I get error:

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-1017: invalid username/password; logon denied'
```

I have installed Oracle client 12c x64

Please let me know how to use Kerberos Authentication using ODP.NET unmanaged data access driver.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957076/cant-connect-to-oracle-using-windows-authentication-with-odp-net